# How to Change Culture setting for Website on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Website developed in ASP.Net Core MVC.

On localhost, the currency displays the local currency ZAR, as it should (String.Format("{0:C0}", value))

When published to Azure, it displays $.
I did change the Portal Settings regional format to South Africa - but I think that only related to the portal and not your websites hosted on Azure.

How do I get my website only to display the local currency?
All my users are local businesses, and I don't require foreign currencies.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the startup class in .net core project. For your reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5260304/ASP-NET-Core-3-0-MVC-Request-Localization-or-How-t

Comment: I've added 
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-FR");
            });
To the public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
and added:
app.UseRequestLocalization(); to the public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IDbInitializer dbInitializer)

On Localhost, I can see the effect of changing the country but it has no effect on published Azure...that remains $. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6, we got it working with this code in Program.cs: -

```
// Configure services etc above here...

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

    await next(context);
});
```